# Why does knitting fail for inline code referring to this simple cor.test?

Tags: r, knitr

I am preparing a .Rmd document that knits to PDF (though the error I will describe also occurs knitting to html).

What follows is a chunk, and then two short paragraphs with in-line code. 
In the chunk I set up two simple variables (anyo and tasa) to later report correlation `cor()`, and correlation test `cor.test()` statistics, as follows:

````
```{r}
#la variable independiente ("X") sea año:
(anyo <- c(1960, 1970, 1975, 1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 1997, 2000, 2003, 2005))
# y la variable de respuesta, la dependiente Y, sea tasa
(tasa <- c(26, 20.7, 17.2, 14.1, 12.6, 10.8, 9.2, 7.6, 6.9, 6.9, 6.2))
e2.prCor <- cor.test(anyo, tasa)
e2.prCor$p.value
```

a) Probar la significancia de la correlación entre las dos variables  
La correlación entre las variables `anyo` y `tasa` es 
`r round(cor(anyo, tasa),3)` (Pearson's product-moment correlación).
Podemos probar la correlación así, contra una hipótesis nula (implícita)
de ninguna correlación:  ` (e2.prCor <- cor.test(anyo, tasa))`  

Resulta que la correlación `r round(cor(anyo, tasa), 3)` es significativamente 
negativa (t=`r round(e2.prCor$statistic, 3)`, p = ` e2.prCor$p.value`),
con intervalos de confianza de 95% de (`r round(e2.prCor$conf.int[1],3)`,
`r round(e2.prCor$conf.int[2],3)`)
````

At the end of the chunk I have added two lines of code that cause the knitting operation to fail if I include them as in-line code, but are fine inside the chunk.  To confirm, the code i include above executes fine, however, if i activate either of the two last lines in their in-line context (I have removed the `r` from before both **`(e2.prCor <- cor.test(anyo, tasa))`** and **`e2.prCor$p.value`**). They can be executed in insolation but the knitting operation fails with the following respective errors:

activating **`(e2.prCor <- cor.test(anyo, tasa))`** causes:
[image: error1]

whereas activating **`e2.prCor$p.value`** causes:
[image: error2]

Given that the commands work within the chunk, and that other calls to elements of the `cor.test` object work in-line, I am a bit stumped. I figure it must be either daft or interesting.

Can you help?

- Note that the colour changes above following the apostrophe in Pearson's, only appears here in SO and not on my computer.

Comment: It looks the second error is one of rendering exponents in-line, and I just found that a work-around was provided [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/160). Enveloping the `e2.prCor$p.value` call with $ $ knits fine for my purposes.

Comment: You can post that as an answer.

Comment: @dhd The object created by `cor.test` is a nine element list. It doesn't really make sense to try and display this result inline and is causing knitr to fail when it tries anyway.

Comment: @wkmor1, so of the two options I proposed for the type of problem, daft or interesting, you're going with daft?  Perhaps you are right. I hadn't stopped to think about at what level of complexity it might cease to be useful to display results in-line.  Ironically, I presume that if I saw it displayed in-line i might have realised that I didn't want it like that after all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the second error type was one of rendering the exponent notation in-line.

A work-around for this and some other scientific notation problems can be found [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/160) as a known - and resolved - issue at git.

The work-around involves enveloping the `r e2.prCor$p.value` call with $ $. After that modification the doc knits fine for my purposes, and renders like this:

[image: rendered content with p.value call activated]

The first error however, caused by activating the `cor.test()` element in-line, is not resolved.